# Migrating from TFS to VSTS - Validation Failing on Personas. Can I uninstall?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-extensions

We're planning a High Fidelity migration from TFS to VSTS using the TfsMigrator tool and ahead of that, we've been running the recommended validation to get the project collection in a ready state.

The validation is unfortunately currently failing on an installed agile extension - Personas. The validation error is as below:

> Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\ProductBacklogItem.xml:: VS403121: Extension(s) "agile-extensions.personas" does not exist , or has no work item form contribution.

The general consensus among the project stakeholders is that the Personas extension be removed entirely from the collection and reinstalled post-migration. I am not entirely sure though what would be the consequence of this and whether it is even the correct approach to adopt.

Answer (score 0):

You could uninstall this tool from your TFS, and then reinstall it again, view the result.

In addition, if you get any issue about this extension tool, you could post an issue under the Q&A here or  email support@agileextensions.com:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=agile-extensions.personas#qna

You would get dedicated support from the extension tool experts.